How to aggregate multiple transactions to show complete trades in one row in Google Sheets?
I have a table in Google Sheets that logs individual transactions for various stock symbols, structured as follows:

I want to aggregate these transactions to show complete trades in a summarized format like this:

Each row in the output represents a complete trade, aggregated from multiple transactions. For each trade, I need to calculate the average entry time, average exit time, total quantity, average entry price, and average exit price.
Here is the sample document
I tried these solutions given by @player0. It's working perfectly. The only catch is that it combines these two WMT trades into one WMT trade and it doesn't show the actual size. Other than that, it's working really well.
How to combine data from multiple rows into a single row based on numbers and certain texts in Google Sheets?
Any assistance on how to achieve this in Google Sheets would be greatly appreciated!

based on what logic should WMT not be joint under one? also how is J4 from your picture = to AM ? total quantity is sum of positive quantity?

Apologies for the J4 error. I gpt it working by following your advice from a post 2 yrs ago. The issue was that the data needed to be sorted in desc order for the helper column to function correctly. Now, the only remaining issue is with the quantity. In the current sheet, for example, CDXC should have a quantity of 100, but it's showing as 4. Could you please take a look at this?
Tab --> RawData1.4
d26 shows quantity is 100, but O13 shows 4.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQzZII-LFy9RJVXVUHl3CxHJ1-7qN8886FKQ_i7zQyZ1c4QpF8SHTuKE9P5mKbUUYkJ1OgYCXUR1P7y/pubhtml

@player0 There are two trades involving WMT:
first, buy 1 and buy 2, then sell 3 which closed the trade. Now, there's a second trade where I bought 1 again, bought 2 again, and sold 3. I was able to figure out how to separate these two trades using your previous answers. Thank you

answer added. fixed your formula and optimized for speed. also removed RT dependency.


I was able to figure out how to separate these two trades using your previous answers

...so I skipped this step and just added Total Quantity as per your request and also optimized for speed, removed dependency for RT helper and shortened the 2 years old formula to make it more readable
see:
={SPLIT("Date♦AV Entry time♦AV Exit Time♦Symbol♦Total Quantity♦AV Entry Price♦AV Exit Price", "♦");
 INDEX(LET(
 a, A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(, 0/(A:A<>""))),  
 b, OFFSET(a,,1), 
 c, OFFSET(b,,1), 
 d, OFFSET(c,,1), 
 e, OFFSET(d,,1), 
 r, ROW(a),
 g, MMULT(1*TRANSPOSE(IF((TOROW(r)>=r)*(c&a = TRANSPOSE(c&a)), d, 0)), r^0), 
 p, (d>0)*(g>0), 
 n, (d<0)*(g<1), 
 q, IF((d>0)*COUNTIFS(a&c&p, a&c&p, r, "<="&r), {b, e, d}, ), 
 w, IF((d<0)*COUNTIFS(a&c&n, a&c&n, r, "<="&r), {b, e}, ), 
 u, SPLIT(UNIQUE(c)&"×0♦0", "♦"), 
 z, IF(d>0, COUNTIFS(c&p, c&p, r, "<="&r), ), x, COUNTIFS(c, c, r, "<="&r),
 m, a&c&VLOOKUP(r, IF(IF(a="",,IF(VLOOKUP(c&"×"&x-1, {u; c&"×"&x, g}, 2, )<>0,,z))<>"", 
                  {r, IF(a="",,IF(VLOOKUP(c&"×"&x-1, {u; c&"×"&x, p}, 2, )<>0,,z))}), 2), 
 QUERY(QUERY({a, c, q, w, m}, 
 "select Col1,avg(Col3),avg(Col6),Col2,sum(Col5),avg(Col4),avg(Col7) 
  where Col1 is not null group by Col1,Col2,Col8"), "offset 1", )))}


spreadsheet demo

Thank you so much for your help with the project! I still feel it's so generous to receive this kind of assistance for free. Blessings to you and your family


Here's one approach you may test out. Tested with both the datasets:
=let(Ξ,choosecols(scan({0,0},D2:D,lambda(a,c,let(x,index(a,,2),Σ,offset(c,,-1),if(c="",,if(or(x=0,Σ<>offset(Σ,-1,)),{+a+1,x+c},{+a,x+c}))))),1),
 Γ,map(unique(tocol(Ξ,1)),lambda(Δ,let(Σ,filter(A2:E,Ξ=Δ),x,lambda(Λ,ifna(filter(Λ,index(Σ,,4)>0))),y,lambda(Λ,ifna(filter(Λ,index(Σ,,4)<0))),
 hstack(+index(Σ,,1),average(x(index(Σ,,2))),average(y(index(Σ,,2))),+index(Σ,,3),abs(sum(y(index(Σ,,4)))),average(x(index(Σ,,5))),average(y(index(Σ,,5))))))),sort(Γ,1,1,2,1))





Format the Date & time columns as needed after applying the formula


Wow! Thank you so much for this. This works like charm! Thank you so much for putting in so much effort to solve this.
